# Modifying existing Crystal Reports to include additional filters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an existing report that I didn't make. It is pretty complicated. It does not use the command function, so I cannot directly change the filters in the SQL code. I have reviewed several links that basically say that there is no way around this and that I will need to create a new command and redo the report. I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve me redoing the report.

My logic that I need is to only select subcontracts that only have one instance (regardless if approved or not), if they have two instances associated only choose the one that has been approved

This is the current backend Crystal SQL

```
   SELECT columns 
    from several tables joins etc 
  WHERE  subcontract = '12345'--parameter entry
   AND company=1 --parameter entry
```

I would like to add this logic which works in a normal sql statement but since I can't modify Crystal's SQL I am stuck...

```
   AND ((subcontract in (select subcontract from table
    group by subcontract having count(*) = 1))
  OR (subcontract in (select subcontract from table group by subcontract  having count(*) > 1)  
 AND "approved = 'Y'))
```

I have looked at you the Select and Group Expert but I am just not getting there. Has anyone found some simple work-arounds? 
Thanks!!!

edit: I already have a select expert that involves subcontract but I don't know how to add what I want to it since it is validation based and I am wanting to add a filter component to it..

```
(
if (IsNull({?BeginSub}) or Trim({?BeginSub})="") then
    true
else
    {subcontract} >= Trim({?BeginSub})
 ) and
 (
 if (IsNull({?BeginSub}) or Left(Trim({?BeginSub}),3) in ["","zzz"]) then
    true
else
    {subcontract} <= Trim({?EndSub})
 )
```

Edit Update: I have found a way to get what I want in crystal reports but it **throws an error when I run the report from my application**. I create a command with the conditions that I want and then link to the other tables where command.subcontract=othertables.subcontract.

Comment: how do you check if contract is approved or not? what is your database structure? How data looks like

Comment: There is a YN column for whether a project is approved or not. The problem is that they can approve pieces of the contract so a contract could have a record of Y approved and N not approved. Also they need to access projects that have not been approved to push them through the system. So I need to make my data set include those subcontracts that have only one instance and if they have more than one instance only include those with approved status.

Comment: My question is are Y and N recorded in same column or another column

Comment: Y  and N are in the same column, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed.. I added the following sql expression field,

```
      (Select count(subcontracts) from subcontract table)
```

then I added the following to the select expert

```
        if(({%SubContractCount} <>2) or ({%SubContractCount}>1 AND  
       approved = Y)) then true else false
```

Thank you!!